# How to replicate MAMP configuration to Ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mamp

I'm having an annoying problem, i've developed a MVC php application, which of course uses a lot of redirects by controllers to controllers and so on.

Well, here's the issue.
On my MACs (note that i'm using a plural) works fine. Different versions of OSX, same version of MAMP on each one, same configuration of MAMP on each one. Even on the macBook Pro of the my office colleague it works fine with MAMP.

But when i move my application on a ubuntu server it causes a REDIRECT LOOP 
between the login controller and the home.

After various experiments i think that the problem is the different configuration from MAMP to UBUNTU.

On MAMP i'm using the php 5.6.10 Version, enabled mod Rewrite (i use .htaccess to rewrite the url). Well, i would like to try to move my MAMP config to the ubuntu server. But i don't know how.

In MAMP i have 2 possible directories where the php.ini is located.

1) bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini

2) conf/php5.6.10/php.ini

Both of them are edited at the same way. I also think that the problem is inside the Apache2 config and not inside the PHP config, but i'm not 100% sure.

Keep in mind that i'm not very familiar with the htaccess files, so the rules inside my htaccess comes from a codecourse tutorial. But however on MAC it works...

However, here's the .haccess file that handles the URL rewrite:

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /astrid/public

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8' css
```

Also if you want to take a look to the project code here's the git repository:
[Astrid](http://github.com/caiuscitiriga/astrid.git)

I'm stuck and i don't know how to figure this out! D: Any kind of help is extremely appreciated! Thank ya'll!